# Is it possible to run Docker container and show its graphical application window on host?

Tags: xorg, docker, container, x11-forwarding

I have created the simpliest (minimal working example) `Dockerfile` to run graphical application on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS host system with 19.10 insider container:

```
mkdir ~/docker-xclock

cat > ~/docker-xclock/Dockerfile << EOF
FROM ubuntu:19.10
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y x11-apps
CMD xclock
EOF
```

Then created container with

```
docker build -t ubuntu:xclock ~/docker-xclock
```

When I try to run this container it shows the error about display:

> ```
> $ docker run ubuntu:xclock 
> Error: Can't open display:
> ```

What is wrong?

Comment: Is "FROM ubuntu:1**9**.04" correct or a typo?

Comment: See also [Run simple X11 app in docker container on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1249043/156688) if you installed docker with snap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need to inform container about running X11 server on host with special syntax [1]:

```
docker run -e DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --user="$(id --user):$(id --group)" ubuntu:xclock
```

[image: xclock on docker]

where [2]:

> **-e, --env=[]**
> Set environment variables
> **-u, --user=""**
> Sets the username or UID used and optionally the groupname or GID for the specified
> command.
> **-v|--volume[=[[HOST-DIR:]CONTAINER-DIR[:OPTIONS]]]**
> Create a bind mount. If you specify, -v /HOST-DIR:/CONTAINER-DIR, Docker
> bind mounts /HOST-DIR in the host to /CONTAINER-DIR in the Docker
> container. If 'HOST-DIR' is omitted,  Docker automatically creates the new
> volume on the host.  The OPTIONS are a comma delimited list and can be:

---

Reference:

1. https://forums.docker.com/t/x11-forwarding-with-v-on-docker-run-not-working/17708/4
2. [`man docker-run`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/docker-run.1.html)

---

Complete reproducible solution:

```
mkdir ~/docker-xclock

cat > ~/docker-xclock/Dockerfile << EOF
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y x11-apps
CMD xclock
EOF

docker build -t ubuntu:xclock ~/docker-xclock

docker run -e DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --user="$(id --user):$(id --group)" ubuntu:xclock
```

Comment: Exits with error message `docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for ubuntu:xclock not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown`

Comment: It is 2021, so 19.10 is EOL. I updated answer above to use 20.04 LTS. Thanks!

Comment: The switch `--user="$(id --user):$(id --group)"` did nothing for me (Arch linux), I got the error `No protocol specified Error: Can't open display: :0` with or without that option. Running `xhost local:docker`, as mentioned in the [answer below](https://askubuntu.com/a/1304947/52781), fixed this for me.

Comment: Fails for me even after running the xhost command. :(

Answer (score 2):

if you're still getting error like:

```
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: :0
```

make sure you run

```
$ xhost local:docker
```

**-from https://github.com/jessfraz/dockerfiles/issues/6#issuecomment-266230114*

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 20.10 :(

Answer (score 0):

Create `Dockerfile` in the folder `docker-xclock`.

```
mkdir ~/docker-xclock

cat > ~/docker-xclock/Dockerfile << EOF
FROM ubuntu:19.04
ENV https_proxy="xxx"
ENV http_proxy="xxx"
ENV no_proxy="xxx"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y x11-apps
CMD xclock
EOF

docker build -t ubuntu:xclock ~/docker-xclock

docker run -e DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --user="$(id --user):$(id --group)" ubuntu:xclock
```

NB: `ubuntu:xclock` put at the end of the command. Using X11 for GUI interaction .