# Run simple X11 app in docker container on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: xorg, gui, docker

I am following [this](https://medium.com/@l10nn/running-x11-applications-with-docker-75133178d090) example of how to run an X11 app in a docker container. I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and using X11:

```
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y x11-apps
ARG user=hakon
ARG home=/home/$user
RUN groupadd -g 1000 $user
RUN useradd -d $home -s /bin/bash -m $user -u 1000 -g 1000 \
        && echo $user:ubuntu | chpasswd \
        && adduser $user sudo
WORKDIR $home
USER $user
ENV HOME $home
COPY entrypoint.sh .
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

where `entrypoint.sh` is:

```
echo "DISPLAY=$DISPLAY"
xclock  # <-- This is the X11 application I am testing with. It shows a clock in a Window
echo "Done."
exec bash
```

I build the image using:

```
$ docker build -t gui-test-ubuntu-2004 .
```

Then run the container with:

```
$ docker run -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
       -h $HOSTNAME -v $HOME/.Xauthority:/home/hakon/.Xauthority gui-test-ubuntu-2004
```

The output is:

```
DISPLAY=:0
Error: Can't open display: :0
Done.
```

and the `xclock` gui window is not showing. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to run Docker container and show its graphical application window on host?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161646/is-it-possible-to-run-docker-container-and-show-its-graphical-application-window)

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks for the link! It still does not work with `--user 1000:1000`. I tried this command: `docker run -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY  --user 1000:1000 gui-test-ubuntu-2004`. Still the same error message: `Error: Can't open display: :0`

Comment: Try to simply repeat commands from my Q&A then adapt yours. The 1000 is not really constant, it is value of `id -u` and `id -g` (user and group identifiers).

Comment: If I try to build the `Dockerfile` in your [example](https://askubuntu.com/q/1161646/156688), I get error: `Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]`

Comment: Thanks, updated it to actual 19.10.

Comment: Ok with 19.10 it builds the image fine. But when I run the container, I still get error: `Error: Can't open display: :0`

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 20.04, maybe that's the issue?

Comment: It may be in the case when you are running Wayland. Try to switch to Xorg on login screen.

Comment: I think I am already on Xorg. If I type `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` the output is `x11`

Comment: How did you install `docker` ? I installed it with `snap`

Comment: Snap may be a reason, I have installed it as `docker.io` package from default repositories. Then added my user to the *docker* group.

Comment: Yes, I think that `snap` might be the issue here, see [this](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker/issues/256) issue: *"snap causes several restictions. --hostdisplay does not work because it is not possible to share unix sockets from host, in this case the X unix socket in /tmp/.X11-unix"*

Comment: I had to use `$XAUTHORITY` instead of `$HOME/.Xauthority` for the volume mount host location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you installed `docker` with `snap`. According to `mviereck` the maintainer of [x11docker](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker)

> `snap` causes several restictions. `--hostdisplay` does not work because
> it is not possible to share unix sockets from host, in this case the X
> unix socket in `/tmp/.X11-unix`

A workaround is to an `Xephyr X server` with [`x11docker`](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker). Instead of running `docker run ... gui-test-ubuntu-2004`, use:

```
x11docker --xephyr gui-test-ubuntu-2004
```

The second alternative is to remove the `snap` installation of `docker`, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1155962/156688) answer, and then reinstall `docker` with `apt-get install`:

1. Remove docker:

   ```
    sudo snap remove docker
   ```
2. Go to https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/ and choose your Ubuntu version, then browse to `pool/stable/` and download the 3 `.deb` files:

   - containerd.io_1.2.13-2_amd64.deb
   - docker-ce_19.03.11_3-0_ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb
   - docker-ce-cli_19.03.11_3-0_ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb
3. Install them in the following order:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install ./containerd.io_1.2.13-2_amd64.deb
    sudo apt-get install ./docker-ce-cli_19.03.11_3-0_ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb
    sudo apt-get install ./docker-ce_19.03.11_3-0_ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb
   ```
4. Add your user to the docker group to avoid having to type `sudo` to run `docker`:

   ```
   sudo addgroup --system docker
   sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
   ```
5. Restart the computer at this point to activate the new user and group settings
6. Test the docker installation by running :

   ```
   docker run hello-world
   ```

You should now be able to run the original `docker run` command:

```
docker run -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
       -h $HOSTNAME -v $HOME/.Xauthority:/home/hakon/.Xauthority gui-test-ubuntu-2004
```

Comment: For me this was not the answer, I simply ran `xhost + local:docker` first and it worked. Not sure how much of a security risk this is?

Comment: Thank you! Installing via snap was indeed the problem. I simply removed the snap and installed via apt.

Answer (score 6):

Type `xhost + local:docker` before running docker.

Comment: `xhost +` is (almost) always a bad idea™

Comment: On a home LAN, how is it ever a bad idea?

Comment: qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Could not connect to any X display.

Answer (score 1):

I was testing this but it was raising the error.
`standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error`

My docker was installed following the instructions here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

I added the the `#!/bin/bash` on the first line of your **entrypoint.sh** and it's working for me.